# No account of type android forcedroid shell project error

Tags: mobilesdk, android, hybrid

I used `forcedroid create` to create a shell android hybrid-local with smartstore app. After a few errors I had to add additional permissions to the android manifest.

Now I'm getting an error `no account of type com.testcompany.new_hybrid_local.login found`. Any ideas?

My account_type in `string.xml` is set to that same value: `com.testcompany.new_hybrid_local.login`

Comment: I'm guessing other people have spun up new apps with `forcedrod create` without this issue?